# Strange behaviour of lambdas that return `dynamic` in Kotlin/JS interop

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-js, kotlin-js-interop

I want to write a lambda function that returns `dynamic` that ends with an assignment operation. The following does not type-check:

```kotlin
var a: Int?
val f: () -> dynamic = {
    a = 42
}
```

Note: this example is somewhat artificial for the purposes of making it minimal. In reality, I need to assign this lambda to `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange`, hence the type requirement.

`f` has type `() -> Unit` when the type annotation is removed. Why cannot `() -> Unit` be cast to `() -> dynamic`?

Moreover, how come this example type-checks?

```kotlin
val f2: () -> dynamic = {
    print("foo")
}
```

`f2` without the annotation also has the type `() -> Unit`. Why does `f2` type-check and `f` doesn't?

Finally, what is the appropriate way to write `f`? Add a `Unit` or `null` at the end, perhaps? That works but looks rather ugly. Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you can find an answer [here](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-js-lambda-does-not-compile-fun-does/13462), because your problem looks similar to this topic

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.